# How do I increment a date by one month?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have a date and I want to increment it by 1 month. How can I do this?

I'm new to iPhone programming. Can this be done or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to use an [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) for this type of activity, as this has methods like `-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` which will let you add "components" ([NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that represent 1 month or 1 year, etc. for example) onto an existing calendar date.

For some general background reading, you might also want to take a look at the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) as it covers some of this, albeit quite briefly.